# Webdriver Driver Mananger 2.7.0 not getting installed from Nuget with .Net framework 4.5

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, nunit-console, webdriver-manager

I want to use WebDriverManager in my code when I am trying to install the reference from the Nuget Package Manager I get an error.
I have tried updating and degrading the .Net framework.
Can we use WebDriverManager  2.7.0 with .Net framework 4.5?

Error Message seen is :

```
Could not install package 'WebDriverManager 2.7.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework, Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old but I ran into the same issue today and was able to figure it out. You need to install version 2.2.7 instead. WebDriverMangaer version 2.2.8 and above require .Net Standard 2.0 which is only compatible with .NET Framework 4.6.1 and above.